# How to ignore 0's in an Array and print out unique numbers

Tags: c++11

so my program is supposed to use one 5 sized array to store inputted integers. If it's a duplicated integer it would not be stored into the array.

The problem here is there would be 0's in my array indefinitely since i initialized the size to 5. I need to output only the **unique numbers** how would i do so?

One thing i noticed was that without my **unsigned int position;** whenever i enter a duplicate integer it would skip the index;

**e.g.** array[0] = 10, array[1] = 10 // duplicate, array[2] = 20 // inputted 20, this should've been stored into array[1] but it doesn't. 
So i had the position to only increment whenever it's not a duplicate to make sure it's not skipping over the index when a duplicate is entered.

And was there anything i could've done or do a different approach to get my result?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

const unsigned int MIN_VALUE = 10;
const unsigned int MAX_VALUE = 100;
const size_t arraySize = 5;
array <int, arraySize> numberArray = {};

template<size_t size>
bool isDuplicate(array<int, size> array, int value)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
        if (value == array[i])
        {
           return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{

  unsigned int input;
  unsigned int position = 0;

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
  {
      cout << "Enter # " << (i + 1) << " : ";
      cin >> input;

     if (input < MIN_VALUE || input > MAX_VALUE)
     {
        cout << "The number entered is not in valid range of 10 to 100" << endl;
        --i;
     }
     else if (!isDuplicate(numberArray, input))
     {
         numberArray[position] = input;
         position++;
         cout << "The number: " << input << " is unique\n" << endl;
     } 
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only missing part in your code is an additional block below your `else if` block:

```
 else {
     cout << "The number: " << input << " is not unique\n" << endl;
     --i;
 }
```

where you would decrease your position when the value is a duplicate, and warn the user about it.

If I had to update your program while keeping the most of your code I would write:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

const unsigned int MIN_VALUE = 10;
const unsigned int MAX_VALUE = 100;
const size_t arraySize = 5;
// Initialize all array values to 0 (see std::array documentation)
array <int, arraySize> numberArray = {0};

template<size_t size>
bool isDuplicate(array<int, size> arr, int val)
{
    bool ret = false;

    // Do not waste time with invalid values
    if (val < MIN_VALUE || val > MAX_VALUE)
        return ret;

    // Using size_t to express size
    size_t pos = 0;

    // Loop until reaching the end OR a not yet set array value
    while ( pos < arr.size() && arr[pos]){
        if (arr[pos] == val) {
            // Found!
            ret = true;
            break;
        }
        ++pos;
    }

    return ret;
}

int main()
{
  unsigned int input = 0;
  size_t position = 0;

  while (position < numberArray.size()) {
      cout << "Enter # " << (position + 1) << " : ";
      cin >> input;

     if (input < MIN_VALUE || input > MAX_VALUE) {
        cout << "The number entered is not in valid range of 10 to 100" << endl;
     } else if (!isDuplicate(numberArray, input)) {
         numberArray[position] = input;
         // Pre-increment operator is more efficient, see doc.
         ++position;
         cout << "The number: " << input << " is unique\n" << endl;
     } else {
         cout << "The number: " << input << " is not unique\n" << endl;
     }
   }
}
```

It looks like an exercise with a really weird specification. It should be better explained so as to give you a more relevant real-life solution. ;)
Hope this helps.

Comment: The thing is the requirement was that when the user input a duplicate number, it would just ignore it so it pretty much still increments the outer loop to prompt the user to enter the **next #**. So for example: Enter # 1 : 10, Enter # 2 : 10, it would then say Enter # 3 : 20..... it wouldn't decrement it so my initial problem was that there will be a point that the last index of the array is not used at all therefore its 0. And i need to print out the unique numbers only and not the 0's. Thanks!

Comment: nevemind...i got it lol. I was way too fixated on printing out the whole array but i forgot that the position was keeping track of what elements i was using, i could've just printed out the positions instead. Ahahaha thanks for the help though! really appreciated it.

Comment: If the ordering did not matter to you, you could have looked at the `std::unordered_set` which may have solved your problem with fewer lines of code: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/?kw=unordered_set.

Anyway, you're welcome. ;)